# Show Django model/database as HTML table

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Is there a way to show this model:

```
# models.py
class Classes(models.Model):
    Team = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=15)
    Name = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=15)
    ClassCode = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=10)
    MissingClass = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=15)
    MakeUpClass = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=15)
    Note = models.CharField(default='-', max_length=25)
    TuitionPaid = models.CharField(default='Pending', max_length=10)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Classes"
```

As an HTML table, preferably without third party apps? I've got an empty placeholder template under the same app. All the urlpatterns stuff is linked up already.

[image]

(I have a views.py file, it's just not in the image, the views copy.py file is backup

Comment: do you search something like this [modeladmin-objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)?

Comment: idk what that is and how to use it lol

Answer (score 0):

**1** In views.py Import your model at the top of the page

```
from .models import Classes
```

**2** In views.py file create

```
def listview(request):
    data = Classes.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'testpage.html', {'data': data})
```

**3** HTML page

```
<!-- At the top of your page add load static -->
{% load static %}

<!-- In the body of the HTML page add this and continue adding all Fields. I have provided three example below -->
 <h1 class='list'>List View</h1>

       {% for k in data  %}
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Team</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>ClassCode</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>{{k.Team}}</td>
                <td>{{k.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{k.ClassCode}}</td>
            
            </tr>
            
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
```

Comment: When I open the HTML page with the code above, it just shows a large header "List View" and nothing else.

Comment: @dairy  In the second step after the **Data** variable add  
`if data:
        print('working')`  refresh the page then in your Terminal, if you see **working** print it out that means you are receiving data from the database if you do not see working printed out, you may try changing your views.py `from .models import Classes` to `from .models import *` then run code and check if **working** is printed out in the terminal.

Comment: VS Code is weird and gives an import error if i run it in the terminal but if i run `manage.py runserver` the webpage shows. I tried changing to `from .models import *` and the same thing happens. I have something else in my views.py, by the way. `def page(request):
    return render(request, 'testpage.html')`

Comment: Could you please share what error you get in VS code and please check urls.py file if the function **listview** is called properly.  The way I write my urls.py is by first importing `from django.urls import path` then in my URL patterns I would add `path('URL', listview)`. In your attempt was **working** printed in your terminal?